# Ubuntu Login Loop After Google Authenticator installation

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, lightdm

My Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop was working fine until I decided to play around with Google Two Factor Authentication for Linux.

I followed instructions and setup the google-authenticator.

When I restarted, the machine had a loop on login screen - after entering password and OTP from Google App, login screen was being displayed again.

I removed google-authenticator, uninstalled lightdm, installed Gnome, did "chown $username:$username ~${username-home}", but nothing has worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be sure, this is happening for all users. ssh login works, so does console login on same desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You removed the module... but you didn't remove the requirement from your PAM configuration!

If you edited the file `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` you now need to (through a TTY or root-prompt from recovery mode) edit it again and remove the line:

```
auth require pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

If you edited **any** other file in the `/etc/pam.d/` directory, you need to remove that line from whichever files you modified.

Comment: If you had followed my Q/A on this site and did the last section where you applied it to the `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` file, you probably forgot to remove the modifications to other files. This caused login to require the OTP **twice** which causes the loop. I'll bold and make that note a sub-heading in my answer.

Comment: Hi, lightdm is completely removed from system. File /etc/pam.d/lightdm is not present.

Comment: What about `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`? Just do a `ls /etc/pam.d/` and see which files are in there. Cycle through all of them and remove that line if present in any of them.

Comment: cat /etc/pam.d/* | grep 'google' displays nothing.

Comment: Is it still asking for a OTP when you try to log-in?

Comment: No, but the loop on login page is still there, even for newly created accounts.

Comment: Can you find any xsession error logs and edit your question with any errors that may be occurring?

Comment: Ran tail -f and tried logging in, nothing is in logs.

Comment: I've tried several times to reproduce this error by enabling and disabling 2FA on various authentication files and could not reproduce. My guess is that this is not related directly to your main issue, and something else has caused this loop.